# Storing emojis in SQL Server table

Tags: android, sql-server, laravel, emoji

So I have been trying to save emojis received via a POST HTTP request from an Android app into an SQL Server table using Laravel.
Though special characters work fine, emojis give syntax error as following-

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near '☺'. [20018] (severity 15) [(null)] (SQL: UPDATE [dbo].[table] SET [text] = N'☺' WHERE [id] = 63060)

The update query in laravel is as follows-

```
\DB::statement("UPDATE [dbo].[table] SET [text] = N'".$data['text']."' WHERE [id] = ".$facebook_post->id);
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Using SQL Server 2008 and Laravel 5.1 with appropriate collations

Comment: This appears to be a problem with Laravel.  I have no issues using these characters in SSMS.

Comment: I think this could help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/working-with-unicode-emoji-from-ios

Comment: @NavinNagpal what is datatype for text column?

Comment: @Sebastian - Sadly using SQL Server and no such thing as utf8mb4 for it

Comment: @Sebastian utf8mb4 is for mysql

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi - It is ntext!

Comment: can you change it to nvarchar(max) and try again

Comment: Tried that too!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135591/discussion-between-chintan-udeshi-and-navin-nagpal).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials and errors, finally got to work by using **base64 encoding/decoding**. Doesn't seem to be the ideal solution. I guess the issue is due to some problem between Laravel and MSSQL (or the config used).
Hoping it is of help to someone.
Also any other better solution is really welcomed!